# Datacontext ExecuteCommand parameters in IN statement

Tags: c#, linq, command, datacontext, execute

What is the best way to run a custom `sql` statement using `IN` from a C# LinQ to sql datacontext? I have tried:

```
db.ExecuteCommand(
   "UPDATE tblCard SET used = 1 WHERE id IN ({0}) AND customer_id = {1}",
   Request.Form["ids"], customer_id
);
```

Which is fine for 1 item passed through the form, but if i get posted through for example "2,1" then I get a `sqlclient` exception:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2,1' to data type int.

If instead I use string.format to insert the parameter it works fine, but obviously this is open to sql injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL doesn't use concatenation; that will be a TSQL query of the form:

```
WHERE id IN (@p0)
```

with `@p0` set to `'123,456,789'`.

With regular LINQ you could use `Contains`. With `ExecuteQuery` there are a few options; you could, for example, pass in the CSV "as is", and use a UDF to split this at the database, and join to it:

```
UPDATE c SET c.used = 1
FROM dbo.SplitCsv({0}) udf
INNER JOIN tblCard c
        ON c.Id = udf.Value
       AND c.Customer_ID = {1}
```

Where `dbo.SplitCsv` is one of the many such "split" udfs available on the internet.